# I want change string value with a content variable progmatically

Tags: android, eclipse, string, variables, if-statement

I've create this code but don't function, how can I do?
I want the contents of the string takes a different value depending on the variable..

```
if ((euro9 == 0) && (cent9 == 00)) {
                    String msg1 = "Euro:"+MailA.this.euro1+","+MailA.this.cent1+"   "+"Motivazione:"+MailA.this.motivazione+"\n";
                    String msg3 = "Euro:"+MailA.this.euro3+","+MailA.this.cent3+"   "+"Motivazione:"+MailA.this.motivazione2+"\n";
                    String msg4 = "Euro:"+MailA.this.euro4+","+MailA.this.cent4+"   "+"Motivazione:"+MailA.this.motivazione4+"\n";
                    String msg5 = "Euro:"+MailA.this.euro5+","+MailA.this.cent5+"   "+"Motivazione:"+MailA.this.motivazione5+"\n";
                    String msg6 = "Euro:"+MailA.this.euro6+","+MailA.this.cent6+"   "+"Motivazione:"+MailA.this.motivazione6+"\n";
                    String msg7 = "Euro:"+MailA.this.euro7+","+MailA.this.cent7+"   "+"Motivazione:"+MailA.this.motivazione7+"\n";
                    String msg8 = "Euro:"+MailA.this.euro8+","+MailA.this.cent8+"   "+"Motivazione:"+MailA.this.motivazione8+"\n";
                    String msg9 = "";

                }

                if ((euro9 != 0) && (cent9 != 00)) {
                    String msg1 = "Euro:"+MailA.this.euro1+","+MailA.this.cent1+"   "+"Motivazione:"+MailA.this.motivazione+"\n";
                    String msg3 = "Euro:"+MailA.this.euro3+","+MailA.this.cent3+"   "+"Motivazione:"+MailA.this.motivazione2+"\n";
                    String msg4 = "Euro:"+MailA.this.euro4+","+MailA.this.cent4+"   "+"Motivazione:"+MailA.this.motivazione4+"\n";
                    String msg5 = "Euro:"+MailA.this.euro5+","+MailA.this.cent5+"   "+"Motivazione:"+MailA.this.motivazione5+"\n";
                    String msg6 = "Euro:"+MailA.this.euro6+","+MailA.this.cent6+"   "+"Motivazione:"+MailA.this.motivazione6+"\n";
                    String msg7 = "Euro:"+MailA.this.euro7+","+MailA.this.cent7+"   "+"Motivazione:"+MailA.this.motivazione7+"\n";
                    String msg8 = "Euro:"+MailA.this.euro8+","+MailA.this.cent8+"   "+"Motivazione:"+MailA.this.motivazione8+"\n";
                    String msg9 = "Euro:"+MailA.this.euro9+","+MailA.this.cent9+"   "+"Motivazione:"+MailA.this.motivazione9+"\n";

                }
                sh.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg1+msg3+msg4+msg5+msg6+msg7+msg8+msg9);
```

The strings can't be call, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do that instead :

- First declare your variable (outside brackets in order to be accesible after them)
- Assign a value
- Use them

But the code bellow is SO repetitive and you should avoid doing it this way.
See the end for an alternative

```
String msg1, msg2, msg3, msg4, msg5, msg6, msg7, msg8, msg9;
    if ((euro9 == 0) && (cent9 == 00))
    {
        msg1 = "Euro:" + MailA.this.euro1 + "," + MailA.this.cent1 + "   " + "Motivazione:"
                + MailA.this.motivazione + "\n";
        msg3 = "Euro:" + MailA.this.euro3 + "," + MailA.this.cent3 + "   " + "Motivazione:"
                + MailA.this.motivazione2 + "\n";
        msg4 = "Euro:" + MailA.this.euro4 + "," + MailA.this.cent4 + "   " + "Motivazione:"
                + MailA.this.motivazione4 + "\n";
        msg5 = "Euro:" + MailA.this.euro5 + "," + MailA.this.cent5 + "   " + "Motivazione:"
                + MailA.this.motivazione5 + "\n";
        msg6 = "Euro:" + MailA.this.euro6 + "," + MailA.this.cent6 + "   " + "Motivazione:"
                + MailA.this.motivazione6 + "\n";
        msg7 = "Euro:" + MailA.this.euro7 + "," + MailA.this.cent7 + "   " + "Motivazione:"
                + MailA.this.motivazione7 + "\n";
        msg8 = "Euro:" + MailA.this.euro8 + "," + MailA.this.cent8 + "   " + "Motivazione:"
                + MailA.this.motivazione8 + "\n";
        msg9 = "";

    }

    if ((euro9 != 0) && (cent9 != 00))
    {
        msg1 = "Euro:" + MailA.this.euro1 + "," + MailA.this.cent1 + "   " + "Motivazione:"
                + MailA.this.motivazione + "\n";
        msg3 = "Euro:" + MailA.this.euro3 + "," + MailA.this.cent3 + "   " + "Motivazione:"
                + MailA.this.motivazione2 + "\n";
        msg4 = "Euro:" + MailA.this.euro4 + "," + MailA.this.cent4 + "   " + "Motivazione:"
                + MailA.this.motivazione4 + "\n";
        msg5 = "Euro:" + MailA.this.euro5 + "," + MailA.this.cent5 + "   " + "Motivazione:"
                + MailA.this.motivazione5 + "\n";
        msg6 = "Euro:" + MailA.this.euro6 + "," + MailA.this.cent6 + "   " + "Motivazione:"
                + MailA.this.motivazione6 + "\n";
        msg7 = "Euro:" + MailA.this.euro7 + "," + MailA.this.cent7 + "   " + "Motivazione:"
                + MailA.this.motivazione7 + "\n";
        msg8 = "Euro:" + MailA.this.euro8 + "," + MailA.this.cent8 + "   " + "Motivazione:"
                + MailA.this.motivazione8 + "\n";
        msg9 = "Euro:" + MailA.this.euro9 + "," + MailA.this.cent9 + "   " + "Motivazione:"
                + MailA.this.motivazione9 + "\n";

    }
    sh.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg1 + msg3 + msg4 + msg5 + msg6 + msg7 + msg8 + msg9);
```

---

**I strongly recommended you the following approach instead of what is above.**

Create an object in a separate file

```
public class MyObject
{
    public String euro;
    public String cent;
    public String motivazione;

    public MyObject(String euro, String cent, String motivazione)
    {
        this.euro = euro;
        this.cent = cent;
        this.motivazione = motivazione;
    }
}
```

And use it

```
        // Create an instance of MyObject
    MyObject obj = new MyObject("asdad", "fcsfc", "fdsf");

        // Initialize a list that will hold all instances
    HashMap<Integer, MyObject> list = new HashMap<Integer, MyObject>();
    list.put(1, obj);
    // OR
    list.put(2, new MyObject("aaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbb", "ccccccc"));

    // And retrieve your item with
    MyObject my = list.get(2);
```

**In the end, you will be able to do something like :**

```
    if (condition)
    {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, MyObject> entry : list.entrySet())
        {
            MyObject currentObject = entry.getValue();
            msg += "Euro:" + currentObject.euro + "," + currentObject.cent + "   " + "Motivazione:"
                    + currentObject.motivazione + "\n";
        }
    }
sh.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
```

Comment: Your recommended solution is total overkill. Building a new class. Instantiating objects of this new class type. Creating a map to place those objects in it. Then looping through those objects. All to build a string? No. You took the code which was fairly minimal and made it complicated by adding new unnecessary classes and loops.

Comment: The class may be overkill or not, but looping is just way better than all those unreadable code with variable_x naming...

Comment: Use a StringBuilder if that's a concern. This is far from unreadable.

Comment: I put 2 solutions, we will choose to overkill his device or not. And just for info, most of devices have super processor and extra memory. What about not using them ?

Answer (score 2):

Declare the Strings (msg1 ,msg3 etc) out side if loop

the scope of local varibles you are using can be accesible inside if condition only
beacause you declaring them inside if condition

Comment: Where do you see a loop here?